# Java modifiable view on collection

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I'm looking to solve the following problem:
Starting with a collection A, I want to pass some kind of 'view' on that collection (say collection B) to a certain method. The view B does not necessary contain all the elements of the original collection A. If in this method objects are added to or removed from the view (collection B), these changes should also be reflected on the original collection A as well.

For instance (pseudo-code):

1. Start situation:

   ```
   Collection A = {1, 2, 3};  
   View-on-collection B = {1, 2};
   ```
2. Method call:

   ```
   someMethod(B) {  
       B.add(4);  
       B.remove(2);  
   }
   ```
3. End situation:

   ```
   Collection A = {1, 3, 4};
   ```

Does anyone know a neat solution to this problem?

Comment: What if you do `B.remove(3);` given `3` is only in A?

Comment: I'd have said `subList`, but that doesn't quite do what you want (the view seems never to change size, even if you add things to it).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: The view can change size with `subList()`.

Comment: @Keppil: indeed, there was a mistake in my test! Now `subList` seems to do **exactly** what is asked for.

Comment: There will be problems if the original list is altered outside of the list that is returned by subList(...), see java documentation on subList

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use [`List.sublist()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    List<Integer> view = aList.subList(0, 2);

    view.add(new Integer(4));
    view.remove(new Integer(2));
    System.out.println("aList: " + aList);
    System.out.println("view : " + view);        
}
```

Another more general way would be through Guavas [`Collections2.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29), that lets you define a predicate to control which objects should be in the view:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collection<Integer> view = Collections2.filter(aList, new Predicate() {
        public boolean apply(Object arg0) {
            return ((Integer) arg0).intValue() % 3 != 0;
        }});
    view.add(new Integer(4));
    view.remove(new Integer(2));
    System.out.println("aList: " + aList);
    System.out.println("view : " + view);

}
```

Both examples print

```
aList: [1, 4, 3]
view : [1, 4]
```

Comment: Yeah, I also found something like that, but the problem is that subList is not flexible enough for us: we might want to retain some elements that are at random places in the original list, e.g. in the first and third position - I think we don't get there using subList.

Comment: More exactly, the Collections2.filter method in Guava. (the question was about collections, not sets)

Comment: @user1649029: Modified to include a more general view too.

Comment: Beware, you can't add just any value to the view returned by Guava's `Collections2.filter()`. Quoting the [Javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html), "When given an element that doesn't satisfy the predicate, the collection's add() and addAll() methods throw an IllegalArgumentException." Your example works because 4 is not a multiple of 3, but would have failed if you had tried to add 6.

Answer (score 0):

Jacarta collections framework has such functionality. But this framework does not support generics. Take a look on Google Guava. I believe they should support such functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend AbstractList (or what ever abstract type of collection you are using)

In this abstraction, you can take the source collection in the constructor and hold a reference to it and the start and end points of the view of the original list

Override the add/remove/set methods so that those actions are also performed on the source collection also.

i.e.

```
class ListView<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

   int start = 0;
   int end = 0;
   private Collection<T> original = null;

   public ListView(List<T> original, int start, int end) {
       this.original = original;
       this.start = start;
       this.end = end;
       super.addAll(0, original.subList(start, end));
   }

   // Any add/set/remove must also alter the original
```

}

The ListView effectively should be a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to the original list.

Alternatively, and with a bit more work, you could implement the Collection or List interface so that you work directly on the original list in a similiar fashion

You can then call your method or pass the ListView around as you would a normal collection.

i.e.

```
public void doSomeWork(Collection<String> collection);

...

object.doSomeWork(new ListView<String>(original, 0, 2));
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted, it's an effective and transparent solution to the problem?

Comment: Same here. Mine was also downvoted. Somebody probably posted a new answer, saw all of the other ones, and wanted his answer to be on top......

Answer (score -2):

You could always have two different collections, a collection A and a collection B.

Then, whenever you added something to `B`, you would add it to `A`, and whenever removed something from `B` you would also remove it from `A`.

When removing from `A` you would check whether or not `B` contained the object to be removed, and, if so, you would remove it.

However, when adding to `A`, you would not touch `B`.

This might be less space efficient than an optimal solution, but it's not going to change time complexity (except for maybe removals from `A`.)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I think that it does not answer the question. Using two unrelated collections is not a view. The point is probably that the two collections will be used in completely different parts of the code, so a manual sync will not be possible.

Comment: @lbalazscs But the point is that you make a new Collection that, inside, works like this. I'm not proposing a manual sync. I'm just saying that in the add method/remove method you do what I have said in my answer.

Comment: I see. But I still wouldn't call this a view. A "view" for me would be like a database view: removing something from the original A would also mean removing from the view B.